# Favour anon user than authenticated user when no basic auth in apache2

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

My need:

1. Be able to authenticate with user in htpasswd file
2. Be able to be an anonymous user
3. Be anonymous user if don't provide basic auth

I also need to know in backend what is the username

With following configuration i can cover 1. and 2.:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.local
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    <Location "/">
        AuthName "Use empty login (or "anonymous" login) and empty password to be anonymous"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider anon file
        AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/passwords"

        Anonymous_NoUserID on
        Anonymous_MustGiveEmail off
        Anonymous anonymous

        Require valid-user
    </Location>

    # To know what is username
    RequestHeader set X-Remote-User expr=%{REMOTE_USER}
</VirtualHost>
```

Demonstration:

```
# http -a 'bux:bux' test.local
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2018 10:29:26 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.6

hello bux

# http -a ':' test.local
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2018 10:29:26 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.6

hello

# http -a 'anonymous:' test.local
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2018 10:29:26 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.6

hello anonymous
```

But if i don't provide basic auth, apache2 request it:

```
# http test.local
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 457
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Mon, 12 Nov 2018 10:35:51 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Use 'anonymous' & Email address for guest entry"

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at test.local Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

How configure apache to only check htpasswd user if basic auth provided ?

Comment: You can't. The browser won't provide basic auth unless the web server asks for it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Technically it is not a problem for me: I can redirect my users with url like http://login:passwd@test.local